# Do you not think that before the word "necessary" the word "is" should be?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

1. Do you not think that before the word "necessary" should be the word "is"?
2. Do you not think that before the word "necessary"  the word "is" should be?
3. Do you not think that before the word "necessary" it should be the word "is"?

Can you tell me which option is grammatically correct? I *<strike>am in</strike> have my* doubts.

Comment: None of the examples are exactly "preferred", since native speakers would normally put the adverbial clause *(before the word "necessary")* at the end, rather than before (an inverted version of the sequence of) the "substantive" element: *Don't you think **the word "is" should be** before the word "necessary"?* But they're all perfectly credible - a pedant might object to the dummy "it" in #3, but actually this is perfectly natural in conversational contexts.

Comment: So the inversion is not possible here?

Comment: It's *possible*, but you do need to take on board that it's more *common* not to introduce stylistic inversions like that unless there's a good reason (which probably doesn't apply to your examples).

Comment: Consider a much simpler example: *At least I know my alphabet! I know that **A** comes before **B*** is far more natural than *I know that before **B** comes **A*** in any normal conversational context. The inverted version is poetic / florid / affected, but perfectly grammatical.

Comment: The examples all put the is in the wrong place. There is just no doubt about it. Why are you talking about inversion?? Also, it is more natural to say; Don't you think. We generally would say:  Don't you think that the word "is" should ***go*** or ***precede*** the word necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is just a template or an actual scenario, and whether you're looking for solutions that involve typography, for example,  *Don't you think it should read "**is** necessary"*?

Comment: @Lambie, is it correct to say *the word "is" should **go** the word necessary*?

Comment: @dan I meant: the word "is" should go ***before*** the word necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer:

Should someone insist that you start your sentence with  "Don't you think that before..." the final part may be "...there should be...":

Don't you think that before the word "necessary", there should be the word "is"?

Answer (score 2):

None of them would usually be used. I would write

> Do you think that the word "is" should be before the word "necessary"?

or if you feel the need to pose a negative question

> Don't you think that the word "is" should be before the word
>   "necessary"?

Comment: It looks to me as if you and I are in agreement about one thing though. We'd rather see *the word "is" should be* in its natural sequence (and natural *position*, I feel).